# apache zeppelin: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark, nullpointerexception, apache-zeppelin

When running any kind of command in zeppelin, I'm getting a "java.lang.NullPointerException" error - even simple stuff like `sc.appName`. Here's the full text:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:391)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:380)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:828)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:483)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The error seems to point to something with Spark, but I have the location set correctly in zeppelin-env.sh:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
```

The only other fields that I've modified are as follows:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/cloudera/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

My hadoop install doesn't have a "conf" folder, but the yarn-site file is in the indicated location. I'm using anonymous login, not sure if that's relevant. I can run the Spark shell successfully from the command line. I really did try to search around since it's such a common error, but nothing seemed to quite fit this situation. I can also provide the zeppelin-env.sh file if needed. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Analyse the Zeppelin logs; the Spark interpreter can't be started. The logs hold the relevant exception.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Rick. I'm no expert, but it does seem to load the Spark UI:

`INFO [2017-05-18 17:21:48,260] ({pool-2-thread-4} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:266) - Started Spark@29067796{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4040}`

The first place that it encounters problems is here:

`ERROR [2017-05-18 17:22:12,430] ({pool-2-thread-4} Utils.java[invokeMethod]:40) - 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

And it seems to be related to Hive?

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':`

Comment: Hi did you finally resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

This "something with spark" triggered the fixes I made, so my cluster works now.  Having no spark configured in Zeppelin worked, as soon, as I switched to my cluster config, it didn't work anymore.  All the Versions you have, have to fit together, which is

- Zeppelin spark interpreter
- Possible Zeppelin-local spark installation (where Zeppelin's SPARK_HOME points to)
- The remote spark master/cluster installation Version

Otherwise, you'll see on the spark side connection errors, deserialization errors, and similar. (At least, this was the case with me).

In Zeppelin's interpreter logfile, look for "Running Spark version"; this should be the spark version, that is actually used.  I hope that helps!

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the `SPARK_HOME` in `$ZEPPELIN_HOME/conf/zeppelin-env.sh` did the charm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in 0.7.2.. Then i found the error from the logs in `zeppelin/logs/servername-spark-interpreter.out`

My error is conflict of SPARK_JAVA_OPTS and SPARK_EXTRAOPTIONS bcoz i added SPARK_JAVA_OPTS in `spark-env.sh`

So i removed below line from `spark-env.sh`

```
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS=-Dspark.driver.port=53411
```

Then restarted the server. Both `spark` and `zeppelin`.

If you are not sure about any options then do not use those in `spark-env.sh`. Let spark handle it by default.

Answer (score -3):

Seems to be bug in Zeppelin 0.7.1.  Works fine in 0.7.2.

Comment: I have the same issue in Zeppelin 0.7.2